# Debugging a hashmap - Java Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, hashset

Basically its an android app, the user completed a little mental health log, like a dairy. One of the screens has the user select from "12 types of twisted thinking". The user can make multiple selections. The 12 types are stored in the mysql database with primary keys from 1-12. Thats the back story.

The code above is from a class which allows the user to see their logs. When they open the log it pulls the data from the mysql server and displays it in a textView inside android. If the user selected the first 3 types of twisted thinking then the database would return 1, 2, 3, null, null, null, null.....etc up to 12. So the dataset I get looks like that. I then take those numbers 1, 2, 3 and assign them to the names of twisted thinking variable sinside the java class. This mirrors the database. 1 = All or nothing, 2 = blaming others ..... and so on up to 12 = should statements.

The code below works. However, its adding an additional selection to the list each time. For example. If the user only makes one selection- say "allOrNothing". It will print All or Nothing to the textview, however it also adds in "Should Statements". If the user selects "All or nothing" and "Should statements" the it will add "self blaming" to the list. I dont know where or why this phantom selection is coming from. Could someone check over the code below and help me pinpoint it.

```
Integer[] twistedThinking = {allOrNothing, blamingOthers,  catastrophizing, 
emotionalReasoning, fortuneTelling,labelling, magnifying, mindReading, 
minimising, overGeneralisation, selfBlaming, shouldStatements};

 Map<Integer, String> twistedThoughtsMap = new HashMap<>(); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(allOrNothing, "All or Nothing Thinking"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(blamingOthers, "Blaming Others"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(catastrophizing, "Catastrophizing"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(emotionalReasoning, "Emotional Reasoning"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(fortuneTelling, "Fortune Telling"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(labelling, "Labelling"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(magnifying, "Magnifying the Negative"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(mindReading, "Mind Reading"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(minimising, "Minimising the Positive"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(overGeneralisation, "Over Generalisation"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(selfBlaming, "Self-Blaming"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(shouldStatements, "Should Statements");

 Set<Integer> selectedSet = new HashSet<>(); for (Integer keys :   twistedThinking) {
 if (twistedThinking != null) {
    selectedSet.add(keys);
 } }
 StringBuilder selectedThoughtsSB = new StringBuilder();
 for(Integer key : selectedSet) {

 selectedThoughtsSB.append(twistedThoughtsMap.get(key) + "\n");
 } distortionLogDetails.setText(selectedThoughtsSB.toString());
 }
```

This is an example of the data returned from the mysql server to Android.

```
"allOrNothing": null, 
"blamingOthers": null, 
"catastrophizing": null, 
"emotionalReasoning": null, 
"fortuneTelling": "5", 
"labelling": null, 
"magnifyingTheNegative": "7", 
"mindReading": "8", 
"minimisingThePositive": "9", 
"overGeneralisation": null, 
"selfBlaming": null, 
"shouldStatements": null
```

Comment: `if (twistedThinking != null) {` this is always true in your for loop. Step by step with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking `keys != null`, not `twistedThinking != null`. The extra `HashMap` value you're getting is for the key `null`. The following code should work.

```
Integer[] twistedThinking = {allOrNothing, blamingOthers,  catastrophizing, 
emotionalReasoning, fortuneTelling,labelling, magnifying, mindReading, 
minimising, overGeneralisation, selfBlaming, shouldStatements};

 Map<Integer, String> twistedThoughtsMap = new HashMap<>(); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(allOrNothing, "All or Nothing Thinking"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(blamingOthers, "Blaming Others"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(catastrophizing, "Catastrophizing"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(emotionalReasoning, "Emotional Reasoning"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(fortuneTelling, "Fortune Telling"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(labelling, "Labelling"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(magnifying, "Magnifying the Negative"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(mindReading, "Mind Reading"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(minimising, "Minimising the Positive"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(overGeneralisation, "Over Generalisation"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(selfBlaming, "Self-Blaming"); 
 twistedThoughtsMap.put(shouldStatements, "Should Statements");

 Set<Integer> selectedSet = new HashSet<>();
 for (Integer keys :   twistedThinking) {
 if (keys != null) {
    selectedSet.add(keys);
 } }
 StringBuilder selectedThoughtsSB = new StringBuilder();
 for(Integer key : selectedSet) {

 selectedThoughtsSB.append(twistedThoughtsMap.get(key) + "\n");
 } distortionLogDetails.setText(selectedThoughtsSB.toString());
 }
```